# Adobe Flex: Substitute list parameter in SQLStatement

Tags: apache-flex

When using SQLStatement objects in Adobe Flex I can use parameters which I can substitute with values later. I have a SQL statement like the following:

```
    SELECT x
    FROM y 
    WHERE z IN (:ids);
```

I would like to substitute :ids with a list which can have any number of elements. I try assigning an Array to SQLStatement.parameters[":ids"] but the condition fails, causing me to believe that the Array is not translated properly into an SQL list. The Array I try to assign contains Strings.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create a comma seperated String?

Comment: Will this not then be interpreted as one value instead of a list of values? I believe that this does not work.